# Como relacionar dos listas con una columna en común en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Estoy comenzando con el lenguaje de Python y me encontré con esta dificultad

Tengo dos listas:

1. **Productos_por_categoria**, son 94 id = producto ordenado en 8 categorias:

```
    Categoria: procesadores
    id [1]
    id [2] 
    Categoria: tarjetas de video
    id [10]
    id [11]
```

2. **Ventas_productos**: Tiene en común el id = producto + las ventas que se realizaron de ese producto

```
{1: 2, 2: 13, 3: 42, 4: 13, 5: 20, 6: 3, 7: 7, 8: 4, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 3}
```

Quisiera saber como hacer una nueva lista o diccionario o tupla para unir ambas listas y que quede asi:

```
Categoria: procesadores
id[1][2] --> id del producto y número de venta
id[2][13]
```

Intenté con el siguiente código pero no sale el resultado esperado:

```
productos_por_categoria = dict(zip(productos_por_categoria,ventas_productos))
print(productos_por_categoria)
```

Resultado

```
{'procesadores': 1, 'tarjetas de video': 2, 'tarjetas madre': 3, 'discos duros': 4, 'memorias usb': 5, 'pantallas': 6, 'bocinas': 7, 'audifonos': 8}
```

*Por último, es posible saber ¿cómo puedo organizar los datos de menor a mayor?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para mejorar la claridad. Puedes hacer ediciones sobre la mía para aclarar algún punto que no haya abordado o para corregir mis cambios.

Answer (score 1):

me gustaría ayudarte pero hay un par de cosas que no entiendo muy bien el cómo las tienes implantadas:
Dices que se tratan de dos listas; no obstante en los productos por categorías no veo exactamente una estructura de tipo lista, lo que quieres es establecer 8 categorías y dentro de cada una de ellas una lista de productos donde cada uno tiene asignado un id? En tal caso entiendo que se trata realmente de un diccionario donde cada clave es una categoría y para cada clave un valor correspondiente a una lista de productos (esta lista se conforma por nºs correspondientes al id de cada producto que conforma la categoría). Si es así entiendo que tendría la siguiente forma:

```
productos_por_categoria = {'procesadores': [idpto1, idpto2], 'tarjetas de video': [aquí habrían maś productos..], categorías restantes...}
```

Por otro lado, tal y como planteas el código de lo que son las ventas_productos, entiendo que no se trata tampoco de una lista sino de un diccionario, donde cada clave es un nº en orden creciente que será igual al id de los productos y el valor para cada clave es el nº de ventas realizadas de dichos productos.

Así pues, partiendo de lo anterior, voy a hacer un ejemplo de como sería si existiesen 2 categorías (procesadores y tarjetas de vídeo) para mostrarte cómo sería:

```
#diccionario de dos categorías donde cada categoría (clave) tiene una lista de nºs donde cada nº es el identificador de un producto (valor)

productos_por_categoria = {'procesadores': [1,2,3], 'tarjetas de video': [4,5,6,7,10,11]}

#diccionario donde cada clave es un id de producto y donde cada valor es el nº de ventas de dicho producto 

ventas_productos = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 42, 4: 13, 5: 20, 6: 3, 7: 7, 10: 1, 11: 3}
```

Una forma de hacer una lista con la forma que planteas, o más bien un diccionario, donde cada clave es una categoría y donde cada valor es una lista de tuplas donde cada tupla se formada por el id y el nº de ventas.

```
#El método get nos devuelve el valor para la clave dada, nen este caso nos devolverá una lista de los id de productos de tipo procesador ([1,2,3] según como lo hemos hecho en el ejemplo)

ids_procesadores = productos_por_categoria.get('procesadores')

#En la siguiente lista guardaremos todos los procesadores cada uno con su id y nº de ventas. La creamos vacía para posteriormente ir rellenándola

procesadores_id_ventas = []

#Con este for vamos a ir recorriendo los ids de procesadores para ir creando el par (id, nº ventas)

for id in ids_procesadores:

    #creamos una tupla donde el primer valor es el id del producto y el segundo valor es el nº de ventas para ese id. Para el segundo valor tomamos el valor para la clave (id) dada del diccionario ventas_productos

    tup_pto_vta = (id, ventas_productos.get(id))

    #guardamos la tupla en la lista de procesadores_id_ventas que creamos anteriormente. Para añadirla usamos append

    procesadores_id_ventas.append(tup_pto_vta)


#Terminado el bucle for que recorre todos los productos de la categoría procesador, pasamos a "refrescar / actualizar" el valor de la categoría procesadores del diccionario productos_por_categoria. De forma que ahora dicho diccionario va a tener como clave el nombre de la categoría y como valor una lista de tuplas donde cada tupla se conforma por el id del producto y el nº de ventas del mismo

productos_por_categoria['procesadores'] = procesadores_id_ventas

#Haciendo lo mismo para tarjetas_de
```

Ahora puedes repetir este proceso para TODAS las categorías consiguiendo mecanizar todo el proceso, `EL RESULTADO FINAL PARA EL EJEMPLO DADO SERÍA`:

```
productos_por_categoria = {'procesadores': [1,2,3], 'tarjetas de video': [4,5,6,7,10,11]}
ventas_productos = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 42, 4: 13, 5: 20, 6: 3, 7: 7, 10: 1, 11: 3}

for categoria in productos_por_categoria:  

    ids_categoria = productos_por_categoria.get(categoria)
    categoria_id_ventas = []

    for id_c in ids_categoria:

        tup_pto_vta = (id_c, ventas_productos.get(id_c))
        categoria_id_ventas.append(tup_pto_vta)

    productos_por_categoria[categoria] = categoria_id_ventas

print(productos_por_categoria)
```

`SALIDA` -->

```
{'procesadores': [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 42)], 'tarjetas de video': [(4, 13), (5, 20), (6, 3), (7, 7), (10, 1), (11, 3)]}
```

Podrás realizar esto con todas las categorías, de forma que tu diccionario inicial productos_por_categorías almacenará todo fusionado tal y como querías.

Comment: Si hay algo que no entiendes o querrías entender como funciona algo en concreto en los bucles o lo que sea, no dudes en preguntar :)